# How to get specific Documents of a Subcollection of all Documents in a Collection in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

So, I have my data ordered in this way :

```
MyCollection                  //main collection       
  --(All documents)           //I want all documents of main collection
     --publicSubcollection    //I want ONLY publicSubcollection of those documents
        --(All documents)     //I want all documents of publicSubcollection
```

And here is how I am doing it in my app:

```
 query = firestore().collection('MyCollection').doc().collection('publicSubcollection')
                .where('act', '==', 1)
                .where('city', '==', this.state.selected_city)
                .orderBy('update_time', 'desc')
                .limit(10);

            query.onSnapshot({
                 //do something
           })
```

and it is returning nothing, empty object. 
I tried calling REST Api using Postman and it also returns empty object. I tried by calling only 'MyCollection' and it returns some data I have in there. So, how can I actually query documents in a specific sub-collection? What am I doing wrong in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It never makes sense to use `doc()` without an argument in a Firestore query.  Without an argument, it generates a DocumentReference with a random document ID.  That ID will certainly not exist, and your query will not return any results.  If you want to query a subcollection, you need to be able to build a path to that subcollection, including **all** document IDs in that path.  There are no wildcard matches in Firestore paths.  In other words, you need to pass a string to `doc()` that identifies which document's subcollection to query.  That document doesn't need to exist - it just needs to be named.

If you are actually trying to query **all** documents in **all** subcollections called "publicSubcollection", you'll need to use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) instead.  It might looks like this:

```
query = firestore()
    .collectionGroup('publicSubcollection')
    .where('act', '==', 1)
    .where('city', '==', this.state.selected_city)
    .orderBy('update_time', 'desc')
    .limit(10);
```